# Sass:math Undefined function. Works in one project but not another

Tags: angular, sass

I have the following SCSS file:

```
@use 'sass:math';
$html-font-size: 16px;

@function stripUnit($value) {
  @return math.div($value, ($value * 0 + 1));
}

@function rem($pxValue) {
  @return #{math.div(stripUnit($pxValue), stripUnit($html-font-size))}rem;
}
```

When a component calls this function, I get an error in my project:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined function.
  ╷
9 │   @return #{math.div(stripUnit($pxValue), stripUnit($html-font-size))}rem;
  │             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  projects\basin-theme\assets\sass\_functions.scss 9:13         rem()
  projects\stories\a-math-test\a-math-test.component.scss 4:10  root stylesheet
```

It all leads back to math.div not working for some reason. I have tried `@use 'sass:math' as math`

These are my package dependencies:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.1.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.10",
    "@angular/common": "~11.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~11.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "~11.1.2",
    "@ngx-formly/core": "^5.10.18",
    "@ngx-formly/primeng": "^5.10.18",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "ngx-mask": "^12.0.0",
    "primeflex": "^2.0.0",
    "primeicons": "^4.1.0",
    "primeng": "^11.4.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1101.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.1.2",
    "@angular/elements": "^13.1.2",
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.7",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.18",
    "@stantec/basin": "0.0.10",
    "@stantec/basin-theme": "0.0.10",
    "@storybook/addon-a11y": "^6.4.14",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.4.13",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.4.13",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^6.4.19",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.4.13",
    "@storybook/addon-storysource": "^6.4.14",
    "@storybook/angular": "^6.4.13",
    "@storybook/preset-scss": "^1.0.3",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "0.0.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@webcomponents/custom-elements": "^1.5.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^5.2.7",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "ng-packagr": "^11.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.1.2",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.49.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.2.1",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.18.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.2"
  }
```

I have tried making this function file work in a new Angular project, and it works fine there. Why isn't it working here? I've spent many hours (into days now) looking for an answer to this and have been unable to find one.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update angular from version 11 to 12 or major and also the version of @angular-devkit/build-angular; should fix the issue.